# Angular: loading image into directive from asynchronous ref

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular and I would like to know if the way I'm approaching something is okay (perhaps until a more solid foundation is established).

I'm creating a DOM from a sequence and tree of custom directives that each add their own content. The application initially loads JSON.

In the JSON there are references to image URIs. As the JSON load is async the directive html templates have already been added to the DOM without reference to the image as it doesn't know what to load until the JSON has provided a reference.

After several JSON files have loaded, I $broadcast an event from the $rootScope that is picked up by listening child scopes.

```
angular.module('applicationDemo').directive("imageContainer", ['ModelFactory', 'Constants', function(modelFactory, constants) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<img ng-src='images/{{theImage}}' width='300'>",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$on( constants.events.ALL_JSON_LOADED, function() {
                $scope.theImage = modelFactory.getPageDataByType('pageStructure').imageId;
            })
        },
        controllerAs: "imageCtrl"
    }
}]);
```

So to check with the community:

1. Is the way the image reference is bound to the imageId that's set asynchronously okay?
2. I've got into the routine of having constants where possible. Is it okay that I'm referencing these via a factory service?
3. In Angular 1.5 (what I'm presently learning) is it okay to $broadcast from the $rootScope, or is this starting to be considered bad practice?

Thank you in advance for your asynchronous advice :-)

Comment: Your directive lacks versatility. What happens if you put two of them on a page?